# Runtime error while usb debugging Android

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to build android apps, this is an app that I am working on as I go through the developer training. The app has been running fine on my android until I tried to add the action bar. Now the app crashes each time I try to start it. There seem to be no errors in my java source file.

Log Cat gives me theses errors:

```
04-30 18:17:28.268: E/Trace(19822): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-30 18:17:29.565: D/libEGL(19822): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-30 18:17:29.917: D/libEGL(19822): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-30 18:17:29.925: D/libEGL(19822): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-30 18:17:30.253: D/OpenGLRenderer(19822): Enabling debug mode 0
04-30 18:17:30.378: W/Resources(19822): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050007}
04-30 18:17:30.659: D/AndroidRuntime(19822): Shutting down VM
04-30 18:17:30.659: W/dalvikvm(19822): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d0f2a0)
04-30 18:17:31.393: E/AndroidRuntime(19822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 18:17:31.393: E/AndroidRuntime(19822): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f020001}
```

.....

I have uninstalled and re-installed the app onto my phone with no difference. All of my drawable files are in the res/ directory.

Here is the source code for the action bar:

```
/* this method is the onCreate for the action buttons in the actionbar */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // this MenuInflater object inflates menu items for use in action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this  problem, I was trying to access a .png that did not exist or I had accidentally deleted.

Comment: correct since the resource was not available because of that only you were getting that exception